# How to send bytes using python (example please!)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sendto

I'm trying to create a simple thingermajigger in python at the moment just to test out sending UDP packets over a socket. I think that I'm getting my script perfectly fine other than using the socket.sendto command. I keep getting errors regarding the portion where "bytes" would go... either TypeError: an interget is required, or when I make it an interget TypeError: a string is required. Could someone provide me with an example of how to send a byte?

the point in my script where I'm getting the error is as follows... please fill out an example as well as a possible explanation / documentation for a newbie.

```
#full script as requested

import socket
import random

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
butes = random._urandom(1024)
 #originally found this as a way to generate bytes to send, but it didn't work out
print("target IP: ")
ip = input()
print("port: ")
port = input()

while 1:
    sock.sendto(butes, (ip, port))
    print("Sent %s amount of packets to %s at port %s." % (sent,ip,port))
    sent += 1
```

Comment: you better provide your whole script, not just one line. otherwise it does not look like you have tried anything

Comment: ***forgot about what I had in for the "bytes" field of the sendto, the "b'0x2E'" was just one of my failed attempted entries to get it to send something***

Comment: python3.3.0 if i'm not mistaken

Comment: I've never seen anyone use `random._urandom`. What's wrong with `os.urandom`?

Comment: found the basics of this script on some website to give me an idea, so I guess os.urandom could also work... also will not be able to reply to any further questions for a while, hope i dont need any extra info for now

Comment: Did you try making `port` an `int` as I suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posted code, `port` is a `str`, you should use `port = int(input())`

Aside: `b'0x2E'` which you had in the original question is 4 characters. If you mean `chr(0x2E)` you can also write `'\x2E'`

Comment: although the socket and such may also not be working correctly, at the moment I was focusing on being able to actually send the bytes... I keep recieveing an error message! i'm on python 3 by the way, if that makes a difference.

Comment: that's so strange... now it's working. I'm using a different computer so perhaps a tiny version change got rid of it and it was a bug.